# How to modify PeopleSoft Reporting Tools Scheduled Query Run Control

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplesoft-query

I am using Oracle's PeopleSoft Campus Solutions and I use Scheduled Queries to run data reports every morning. I am wondering if it is possible to adjust a run control (such as updating the Distribution List or Scheduled Run Time) without needing to cancel the current runs and reschedule the task through the Web Interface for PSQuery. Please note that I am a standard user and do not have backend access. Below are the current versions my organization is utilizing:

```
Tools Release   8.58.20
Application Release Campus Solutions 9.20.00.000
```

Here is a screenshot of the PS Schedule Query Interface for reference:

[image: PS Schedule Query Interface]